SpringBootTest - testing closed context
The application closing context explicitly:
@Service
public class Foo {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public Foo(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

    public void closeContext() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            context.close();
            System.out.println("Context closed");
        });
        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }
}

In the test I want to check that it's closed.
The test:
@SpringBootTest(classes = X12Application.class)
class X12ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws InterruptedException {
       assertFalse(context.isClosed());
       foo.closeContext();
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       assertTrue(context.isClosed());
    }


}

The asserts finish successfully .
But test ends with error:
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext loaded for [MergedContextConfiguration@c2cf597 testClass = com.example.x12.X12ApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.example.x12.X12Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@79da8dc5, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@696da30b, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@693fe6c9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizerFactory$OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizer@306f16f3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@14555e0a, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@a76cda49], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null] is not active. This may be due to one of the following reasons: 1) the context was closed programmatically by user code; 2) the context was closed during parallel test execution either according to @DirtiesContext semantics or due to automatic eviction from the ContextCache due to a maximum cache size policy.

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.publishEvent(TestContext.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener.afterTestClass(EventPublishingTestExecutionListener.java:168)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestClass(TestContextManager.java:538)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


I think this is expected behavior. My guess is Spring tries to close (or interact with) context only to find out that you have manually closed it already. You manually closing the context of a running spring application is something I can't image being a good idea.

there is a reason behind the closing (and reopening) any workaround to allow the test?

You can try mocking the context then instantiate this Foo class yourself and pass your mock in constructor var foo = new Foo(mockContext);. Afterwards just trigger closesContext() and verify that close() was called on the mock object
